# Produce equation of curve, given some coordinates

Tags: algorithms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get equation for a curve which intersects x at seemingly randomly distributed points?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2544/get-equation-for-a-curve-which-intersects-x-at-seemingly-randomly-distributed-po)

I tried [asking something similar to this before](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2544/get-equation-for-a-curve-which-intersects-x-at-seemingly-randomly-distributed-po), but I guess I didn't explain very well. Hopefully this will be more clear.

I need to get an equation which describes a curve with certain points.

For example, I have a list of 5-10 different points along the x-axis where a curve either touches or crosses the x-axis.

Now, how can I get an equation to describe any curve (at least one of the possible curves) which satisfies this?

I'm only concerned with x values within the range of the given values. So, if the curve interacts with the x-axis at other points outside this range, that would be ok too, it doesn't matter....

So to put it another way,

if y = 0; and 0 < x < 100; also x = (list of given points eg. 0,4,17,19,56,67,100)

It doesn't matter what the other x values are when y ≠ 0. And it doesn't matter what other x values might be outside the given range (in this case when x > 100).

Is there any website or free software which can take the coordinates and spit out an equation? Or is there a method you can explain, which I can use to write my own program for doing so?

To be more clear, I'm given a list of points all where y=0, How can I get an equation such that, someone else could look at the equation alone, without also seeing the points I used to produce the equation, but then be able to use that equation to get those same points.... to tell me where the line crosses x within the range I specify?

Also,
If multiple possibilities exist, the shorter length of equation the better.

Comment: If you just want a polynomial with specific zeros, couldn't you just use y(x)=(x-x1)*(x-x2)*(x-x3)...., where x1,x2,... are the x's where the line will intersect the x axis?

Comment: @OscarB. That's basically just listing the x values... But I need it so that there is something to compute. So the next person to see the equation would need to graph/plot it, in order to see where it crosses the x-axis. Something like y=sin(x)+cos(x). OR r=e^(.3x)

Is there a way to generate those types of equations, given whatever coordinates?

Comment: Right - but couldn't you just expand the expression, possibly add a few randomly chosen zeros outside the 0-100 domain? That would make it less straightforward, though Maple and such would easily factorize it. Otherwise, you need to look outside polynomials, in which case, you would need to solve a system to find the coefficients for your basis functions such that they are zero at your chosen points. I guess you could use the Discrete Cosine Basis, in which case you could use the DCT to solve that system. But there are so many choices, and I don't really know what you're looking for.

Comment: If you want an equation that passes through certain arbitrary points but does not list them explictly, you could take the above example and then multiply out the polynomial explicitly. This would mask their contribution.

Comment: @monkeyblot, according to your comment it sounds like you're really asking for a way to encrypt a sequence of (x) values within a function.  That's very different from what you asked.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you want a function that does not obviously yield its roots by observing the equation, but whose roots are easily determined by its graph.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Paul, a short equation is better than a long one. I just guessed that an equation in a form which describes the curve, rather than it's points would be that. I guess I'd better add that to the question - shorter is better... But yeah, if the form which Oscar suggested is actually the shortest way, then that's what I need.

Comment: @monkeyblot: Are you trying to develop a teaching example for root-finding methods?

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is to be able to map from a set of roots back to some combination of elementary functions. Is that correct?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is nothing new about this question.  @monkeyblot - your question was pretty clearly answered in the other thread, I'm sorry but I don't think it's useful for us to try and figure out what you want in comments.